# Easy way to access POJO properties in groovy?

Tags: reflection, groovy, pojo, gstring

I'm new to groovy and still learning my way around.  Is there an easy way to get POJO property values in groovy using dot notation?  For example, I have the following POJO:

```
public class MyPOJO {
        protected String name;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

}
```

In groovy, I would like to get the value of the name field as follows:

```
def doSomething (MyPOJO mpj) {
    def name = mpj.name
    // do something
}
```

The above does not work.  I know that i could still use java getters and setters, but I would like to be able to get to a point where I can dynamically pull pojo values like so:

```
def doSomething (MyPOJO mpj, String propertyName) {
    def propertyValue = mpj.'${propertyName}'
    // do something
}
```

I'm trying to avoid using java reflection.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you explain what does not work for you? Your code works for me.

Comment: That's exactly how it should work with Groovy - with a minor correction, you need to use a GString (double quotes) when accessing a property dynamically `def propertyValue = mpj."${propertyName}"`

Answer (score 0):

Michal - apologies... the first code snippet was working, the second wasn't.

stempler - that worked!  this was gnawing on me.  corrected snippet:

```
def doSomething (MyPOJO mpj, String propertyName) {
    def propertyValue = mpj."${propertyName}"
    // do something
}
```

Comment: if you pass "name" as value for parameter propertyName it works, in other cases it will rise an exception for attempt to access a missing property.